# Print array values repeatedly for 'n' number of times

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have following array:

```
arr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

How can I print its value repeatedly for `9` times?

I tried following and it works fine but any better solution is appreciated:

```
total_elements = arr.length
new_index = 0
limit_value = 9

limit_value.times do |index|  
  if index < total_elements  
    new_index = index
  else        
    new_index = 0 unless new_index < total_elements    
  end  
  puts arr[new_index]
  new_index += 1
end
```

Comment: +1 for the working piece of code and shown effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cycle` + `take`

```
arr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']

puts arr.cycle.take(9)
# >> aaa
# >> bbb
# >> ccc
# >> ddd
# >> aaa
# >> bbb
# >> ccc
# >> ddd
# >> aaa
```

Comment: That's awesome!!!. Thank you a lot. Now I am not regretting to ask such a silly question here :)

Comment: +1, BTW, [`Enumable#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) returns an array; `to_a` is redundant.